# Bluemixにinstallできる ibm-db-dbi をさがしています

Tags: bluemix

requirements.txt にバージョンを記入し、 import しようとしていますが、有効なバージョンが
わかりません。

```
  Collecting ibm-db-dbi==1.8.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ibm-db-dbi==1.8.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: )
         No matching distribution found for ibm-db-dbi==1.8.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
```

ibm-db-dbi の有効なバージョンの調べ方を教えてください。

Comment: ibm-db-dbiを提供しているのはibm-dbパッケージのようです https://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/